# Reported breakthrough with union-closed sets

Tags: combinatorics

I saw a brief newspaper report today of an apparent breakthrough  by Gilmer on a conjecture by [Frankl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9ter_Frankl) regarding union-closed sets. The conjecture is that if a family of sets is "union-closed" then it must have at least one element appearing in at least half the sets.

When I looked at the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.09055), which I do not completely understand, the lower bound developed by Gilmer is far short of the "1/2" conjectured by Frankl. Is the report correct, in the sense of suggesting that the professional mathematics community consider a breakthrough to have been made, and if so, why is it such a breakthrough?

Comment: From the abstract: “This [0.01] is the first known constant lower bound”. This is akin to how Yitang Zhang gave the first upper bound in the twin prime conjecture (they gave $70,000,000$ where the goal is $2$). The point is that having the first constant bound is exciting, and the hope is probably that the techniques used can be perfected over time to whittle the bounded closer and closer to the desired value

Comment: (Disclaimer: I don’t know anything about the field, but this is just why I am not surprised they call it a breakthrough)

Comment: Indeed, Will Sawin pushed Gilmer's method to obtain a ponit contained in a $(3-\sqrt 5)/2$-portion. Here's the link https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.11504.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The comments point out the significance of a constant lower bound. Here is a link

https://www.quantamagazine.org/long-out-of-math-an-ai-programmer-cracks-a-pure-math-problem-20230103/

to an article in Quanta magazine with more details.